# Counting number of non-increasing sequences

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$.
How many ways can we choose 3 numbers to form a non-increasing sequence?
Which of the interpretations are correct?
I'm struggling to see why the second one would be incorrect if the first is correct (which I hope it is):

Let $x_j$ be the number of times the $j$th digit appears in the sequence.
Then we count the number of non-negative integer solutions to
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \ldots +x_7 = 3.$$
This is equal to $\binom{3+7-1}{7-1} = \binom{9}6$.

The second interpretation is:
Since if we choose any set of $3$ numbers, we can always rearrange it into a non-increasing sequence.
So that means it should be done in $7\times 7 \times 7 = 7^3$.

Which one is correct and why is the other one not correct?

Comment: Can the same number be chosen twice?

Comment: I think so, sorry the question was given as it is.

Comment: Actually, in the solution they gave an example $6,4,4$ as a non-increasing sequence

Comment: Why $7^{10}$? Where did the $10$ come from?

Comment: Oh sorry, I have meant $7^3$.

Comment: Yes, that is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is correct.  The second is not because you count different orders of selecting the same numbers separately.  For example, you have counted $123, 312$ and the other four permutations.  It is true that you could arrange them to make a non-increasing sequence, but you have counted six of them.  If you want, you can say you have seven ways to choose all three the same, $3\cdot 7 \cdot 6=126$ ways to choose two of one number and one of another, of which $\frac 13$ are nonincreasing, and $7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5=210$ ways to choose three different numbers, of which $\frac 16$ are nonincreasing.  The total is then $7 + \frac 13 \cdot 126 + \frac 16 \cdot 210=7+42+35=84={9 \choose 6}$

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, the second method counts the number of *non-decreasing* 3-sets incorrectly. Clearly, the idea is supposed to be the following : $\{i,j,k\}$, where $i , j ,k \in A$ form a subset, and since $i,j,k$ are chosen independently with seven possibilities each, we think that the number of subsets is $343$.

We would be right, except that *two subsets could be exactly the same when you arrange them in non-decreasing order, and hence represent the same non-decreasing sequence!* For example, $\{1,2,1\}$ and $\{2,1,1\}$ are exactly the same sequence as $\{1,1,2\}$ when you represent them as non-decreasing sequences. Hence, the concept of picking each entry independently, is leading to overcounting, since these are all counted differently.(A lot of overcounting, given that this answer is more than four times the other).

On the other hand, in the first method this does not happen : If $x_2 = 1$ and $x_1 = 2$, then we know that there can be only one sequence corresponding to this, which is $\{1,1,2\}$. Hence, no overcounting occurs, and this answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Let's define $x_i,~i\in\{1,2,3\}$ is the number at $i-th$ position.
Can we argue something like this: Due to symmetry, I can assume that the number of non-decreasing sequences should be equal to the number of non-increasing sequences. Now, non-decreasing sequence has the form $x_1\leq x_2\leq x_3$.

Suppose $x_1=1$, then $x_2\geq 1$. First, let's choose $x_2=1$. Then, $x_3\geq x_2=1$, and there are $7$ options for $x_3$. If we choose $x_2=2$, then there are $6$ options for $x_3$, and so on. So, if we fix $x_1=1$, then we have $7+6+5+...+1$ different non-decreasing sequences.

Now, suppose $x_1=2$. Then, $x_2\geq 2$. Similarly, we can show in this case we have $6+5+4+...+1$ different non-decreasing sequences.

We can kep increasing $x_1$, until the last case, where $x_1=7$, and only one non-decreasing sequence is possible: $x_1=x_2=x_3=7$.

So, overall the number of non-decreasing (or non-increasing) sequences is:
$(7+6+...+1)+(6+5+...+1)+(5+4+...1)+...(2+1)+(1)=84$