# How to count the number of n-tuples $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ that give a distinct sum?

Tags: combinatorics

Say we have the following $n-$tuple $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ such that $$1\leq x_i\leq 2n,\text{ for all }i=1,2,...,n.$$
I want to know how many tuples exist **which give the same sum**. So for instance if $n=3$:
$$(1,2,1)\equiv (2,1,1)\equiv (1,1,2)$$
because they yield the same sum.

I read some answers to similar questions and found people using the stars and bars technique or Polya Enumeration Theorem (which I don't clearly understand). Furthermore, if I understand the stars bar approach, then we need to know the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i$ which will be equal to the number of stars and then you could throw in the $n-1$ bars. Here the number of stars range from $n$ to $2n^2.$ So maybe I have to do the following sum: 
$$S = \sum_{m=n}^{2n^2} \binom{m-1}{n-1}.$$
Does this make sense?

Comment: here you can use the stars/bars approach in another sense. Notice that you are looking for the number of non-decreasing sequences of numbers between $1$ and $2n$

Comment: see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2491677/counting-number-of-non-increasing-sequences

Comment: In the title you talk about the sum, in the body you do not mention the sum but just talk about the number of tuples.  Which is it?  Please clarify.

Comment: I made the edit! Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: It sounds like your original tuple consists of $n$ distinct numbers in the range $[1,2n]$.  It is not hard to determine the number of orders of tuples that have the same entries in different order.  For example there are ${n \choose 3}$ ways to choose three distinct numbers out of the original set, then $3!=6$ ways to order each of these choices.  Finding $(2,3,4)\equiv (3,3,3)$ is harder because we are not guaranteed that $2$ and $4$ are both there.  I think you are in for a brute force count of them.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the number of [integer compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of integer $m$ into exactly $n$ parts for $n\le m\le 2n^2$.

Their [number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)#Number_of_compositions) is

$$\binom{m-1}{n-1}.$$

Yes, you are right. Their total number is therefore

$$\sum_{m=n}^{2n^2}\binom{m-1}{n-1}.$$