# Number of $n-$ tuples forming a decreasing sequence.

Tags: combinatorics

**Problem Statement:** 
Let $n\geq 2$ be a natural number. We are interested in sequences $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ of natural numbers such that 
$$x_1+x_2+...+x_n = x_1x_2...x_n\text{ and }x_1\leq x_2\leq...\leq x_n.$$
Let $A(n)$ denote the set of all such sequences. Moreover, we denote by $a(n)$ the cardinality of the set $A(n).$  The goal is to generate $a(n)$ for $n\geq 2.$ However, at the moment I am just trying to understand how many non-decreasing sequences I have to check in order to understand the time complexity of a naive algorithm which checks over all the possible sequences. Now it has been shown that for all $n\geq 2$ if $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\in A(n)$  then 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\leq 2n.$$
So I am assuming that each $x_i$ ranges from $1$ to $2n.$ My question is how many non-decreasing tuples do I have to check in order to find $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\in A(n)?$

Comment: @Frpzzd No, this is a number theory problem I have been working for a while now.

Comment: @mfl Yes. I will make the edit.

Comment: Is it allowed to have $x_1\le x_2$ or is it $x_1<x_2$?

Comment: @mfl We can have $x_1\leq x_2.$

Comment: As in your [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2938127/how-to-count-the-number-of-n-tuples-x-1-x-2-x-n-that-give-a-distinct-sum) you start by referring to an $n-tuple$ but you really just have a set.  The order does not matter here.  Then you refer to $n-$tuples, but I believe it is not the same $n$.  Do you really mean the same length?  In the other question it appears that shorter length tuples are of interest as well.

Comment: @RossMillikan Please see the edit. I should have been more direct the first time. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: It looks to me like what you are trying to ask is the number of nondecreasing sequences  of length with maximum element $k$ or less.  Note that once you choose the numbers the sequence is determined, so you are looking for the number of ways to choose $n$ numbers from $[1,k]$ with repetition allowed.  rogerl's hint is a good one if you replace $2n$ with $k$

Comment: @RossMillikan But that is just $(2n)^n$, right?

Comment: No, it is not, because that counts all the different orders of selecting the same set of numbers separately.

Comment: There is a far simpler approach to finding sets of numbers with the same sum and product.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  It has come up several times this afternoon.

Comment: @RossMillikan I am not sure I understand what approach you are referring to. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Note that $1$s contribute to the sum but not to the product.  You need more than one number greater than $1$ in the list or the product will be less than the sum.  Choose the numbers greater than $1$ however you want.  Form the product, subtract the sum.  Add in that many $1$s to the mix and you have a solution.  So if I choose $2,2,3,4$ as my numbers greater than $1$, the product is $48$ and the sum so far is $11$.  I need $37 \1s$ to make the sum and product equal.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: the number of solutions to $1\le x_1\le x_2\le\cdots \le x_n\le k$ is the same as the number of solutions to
$$
1\le x_1 < x_2+1 < x_3+2 < \cdots < x_n+(n-1) < k+n.$$

Comment: Wow. Very nice solution.

Comment: Well, it was. Because the question changed completely.

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear the first time.

Comment: Actually not as much as it looks and your solution is still appropriate.  The sum/product is just motivation.  See my last comment on a rework of the problem that I think is what is wanted.  If you change $2n$ to $k$ your answer works perfectly.

Comment: @rogerl I am not sure I understand how I can use the inequalities to come up with an expression. Could you explain a little more?

Comment: @Hello_World If the integers are distinct (as they are in the strict-inequality version), this is just the problem of choosing $n$ things from $k+n-1$ things.

Comment: So is it justified to say that we have $\binom{n+k-1}{n}$ tuples of this form out of all the $n^k$ tuples?

Comment: Yes, for tuples bounded by $k$. But remember that a tuple bounded by $k$ is also bounded by $k+1$.